# Prevent 'npm publish' from local. Only allow via Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, npm, nexus

I have an Angular library (npm package) which I want to publish to a private nexus repository.
The method of authentication that I keep finding online is to add base64 encoded credentials to the `.npmrc` file under the `auth_` property.

This sounds like it will allow developers to just publish from their local environment by just running `npm publish` though, because the credentials are stored locally.

Is that understanding true? I can't believe that people are okay with that being the case. That seems like a huge issue if people can just deploy new versions of a npm package from their local setup.

What other method can I use to publish this npm package to nexus without exposing the Nexus credentials?